# Using 'as' in between

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis

The university of Chicago has been ranked one of the best in the world.

OR

The university of Chicago has been ranked **as** one of the best in the world .

Which one of them is correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. You can easily find examples of either used on the internet or in books if you search.

However, [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ranked+one+of+the%2Cranked+as+one+of+the&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cranked%20one%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cranked%20as%20one%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the form with "as" is significantly more popular:

[image]

On the other hand, when it's "ranked [as] number" [NGrams show](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ranked+number%2Cranked+as+number&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cranked%20number%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cranked%20as%20number%3B%2Cc0) without "as" is popular:

[image]